# Conda vtk is already installed but python shows - No module named vtk

Tags: python, pip, installation, vtk

I am trying to install vtk for python 2.7 for Windows 64 bit PC

```
C:\Users\Abhi>conda install vtk
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Where as

```
C:\Users\Abhi>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vtk
>>>
```

for pip also I've tried

```
C:\Users\Abhi>pip install vtk
Collecting vtk
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk
>
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk

I've tried installing from executable file https://vtk.org/download/

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Are you sure the python that you are using is the one that you used to install the VTK by using conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be installing VTK for a python environment, but then using another one when you try importing it. It's important to keep track of which python you are using when performing an install.

The way I keep things organized is to create conda environments. If I were you, I would do the following:

Create a conda environment (you can specify any version of python you want)

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
```

Now, you've created an environment in which you can install packages for your own python project. You can create other environments with different packages and versions for other python projects using this command. Next, make sure to activate your conda environment (you must do this every time you start a new session)

```
conda activate myenv
```

Now, after activating your environment, make sure that your environment is indeed active by running

```
conda info --envs
```

The active environment will have a * next to it. Make sure that the * is next to "myenv", not base.

After making sure you are indeed in your active environment, install all packages you need (including VTK). Here's how to install vtk:

```
conda install -c anaconda vtk
```

After you're done installing packages, you can make sure they are installed in your environment by running

```
conda list
```

Scroll down until you see your package.

Now, you should be able to run python scripts with the packages you installed. Test things out by running your import vtk line and let us know if things worked.

Comment: nope.  everything checks out except the import doesn't work.